Laravel 11 database notification data not encoding properly
I'm attempting to save my notifications to the notification database table.
$n = new testNotification($company);
$user->notify($n);

However I keep getting the following error:

Array to string conversion
INSERT INTO
notifications (
id,
type,
data,
read_at,
notifiable_id,
notifiable_type,
updated_at,
created_at
)
VALUES
(
6242fed0 - db16 -4864 - bd68 - 853bc2ada748,
App \ Notifications \ testNotification,
?,
?,
1,
App \ Models \ USER,
2024 -07 -24 12: 00: 13,
2024 -07 -24 12: 00: 13
)

Slack notifications are working fine but database keeps giving errors.
The way I solved this was by adding json encode around the toArray() function but this doesn't seem right to me, as normally laravel should do this encoding by itself, I don't understand why the data attribute is not encoding properly.
public function toArray(object $notifiable)
{
    return [
        'message' => $this->data->name,
    ];
}
       
// Updated version
public function toArray(object $notifiable): string
{
    return json_encode([
        'message' => $this->data->name,
    ]);
}

I created my table using php artisan make:notifications-table
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 */
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->morphs('notifiable');
        $table->text('data'); // Ensure this is TEXT or LONGTEXT
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

I'm also including Notifiable on my user model.

And what happens when you try to use the toDatabase method? ( Documentation )

Try to save some "XYZ" string to the column "type" and then check if it is working.
